# Do i need to change code in rails when i migrate database from sqlite to Postgresql or someother

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite

I am new to ruby on rails framework and build some Blogs,portfolio like applications using rails.For that i used sqlite as my database.
I would like to create a scalable applications and though sqlite is a lightweight database. I would like to change the database as postgresql , Mysql and mongodb etc.

**So my question is if i change the database ,did i need to change rails code 
or it will be same as using sqlite?**

Comment: MongoDB is a completely different beast, you'll have to rewrite a significant portion of your application to make it work there. The only way you're going to get portability between SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL is to do it yourself, AR doesn't help you with the hard parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) is a database-agnostic abstraction. This means your models, and the way you query the tables that they represent, should not change *much* as you swap out the underlying database, provided you are only doing basic [AR querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and you are sticking closely to Rails conventions.

However, it is advisable to use the same database (e.g. Postgres or MySQL) in Development, as you are planning to use in Production, because you can run into issues when you try to deploy your app.

You will need to add the Gem for the database you want to use in your Gemfile:

```
#gem "sqlite3"
gem "pg"
```

And then change your **config/database.yml** to connect to your new database:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: root
  password: 

development:
  <<: *default
  database: yourapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: yourapp_test
```

If you are going to migrate to using Postgres (my personal favorite) I recommend you [watch this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql).

Comment: Thx! Is rails is scalable as .NET or Java(Spring) ?

Comment: I have found Rails to be very scalable indeed. But I am not familiar with scaling .NET or Java in production environments. I recommend Googling it. That particular question won't work on StackOverflow because it is more of an open ended discussion.

Comment: "should not change as you swap out the underlying database", really? AR doesn't give you useful portability at all, it does nothing to help with the hard parts. There are a lot of "it worked when I developed with SQLite but broke in production with PostgreSQL" questions after all.

Comment: @muistooshort - You make a good point. I have tweaked my answer slightly.